# gvimdiff: How to keep width for both windows at 50% when maximizing?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

When I start gvimdiff, the two windows occupy 50% of the window width. Exactly what I want.

However, when I then maximize the gvimdiff window via the window manager, the width of the left window stays as is and all the extra width is allocated to the right window. Is there a way to keep the window width 50/50 when maximizing (or more generally, for *any* horizontal resize operation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an option for this. You can get close with an `autocmd` for the `VimResized` event:

```
autocmd VimResized * normal ^w=
```

Where `^w` is produced by <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>. Or without control characters:

```
 autocmd VimResized * exec "normal \<C-w>="
```

Comment: Sweet! Interestingly, the help for CTRL-W = says *make all windows the same height*; adjusting the width to 50/50 appears to be a side effect.

Comment: Well it says *make all windows the same height & width*, but indeed this is not a perfect solution, although it should be fine for the split vimdiff situation.

Comment: The vim help was updated somewhere between 7.0 and 7.3 to also mention width.